# My videos have a naturalSize of only (4.0, 3.0) pixels, which is also extracted frame size

Tags: swift, avkit

### Context

I'm dealing with video files that are 1280x920, that's their actual pixel size when displayed in QuickTime, or even played in my AVPlayer.

I have a bunch of videos in a folder and I need to stick them together on a `AVMutableComposition` and play it.

I also need, for each video, to extract the last frame.

What I did so far was using `AVAssetImageGenerator` on each on my individual `AVAsset` and it worked, whether I was using `generateCGImagesAsynchronously` or `copyCGImage`.

But I thought it would be more efficient to run `generateCGImagesAsynchronously` on my composition asset, so I have only one call instead of looping with each original tracks.

Instead of :

```
                   v-Get Frame
AVAsset1 |---------|
AVAsset2 |---------|
AVAsset3 |---------|
```

I want to do :

```
                                v----------v----------v- Get Frames
AVMutableComposition: |---------||---------||---------|
```

### Problem

Here is the actual issue:

```swift
import AVKit

var video1URL = URL(fileReferenceLiteralResourceName: "video_bad.mp4") // One of my video file
let asset1 = AVAsset(url: video1URL)
let track1 = asset1.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!

_ = track1.naturalSize // {w 4 h 3}

var video2URL = URL(fileReferenceLiteralResourceName: "video_ok.mp4") // Some mp4 I got from internet
let asset2 = AVAsset(url: video2URL)
let track2 = asset2.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!

_ = track2.naturalSize // {w 1920 h 1080}
```

Here is the actual screenshot of the playground (that you can download [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7795uqnst1y1kq/TrackPlayground.playground.zip?dl=0)):

[image]

And here is something else :

Look at the "Current Scale" information in QuickTime inspector. The video displays just fine, but it's showed as being really magnified (note that no pixel is blurry or anything, it has to do with some metadata)

**The video file I'm working with in QuickTime:**

[image]

**The video file from internet:**

[image]

### Question

- What metadata that information is and how to deal with it?
- Why it is different on the original track than when put on a different composition?
- How I can extract a frame on such videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you stumble across this post, it's probably you are trying to figure out Tesla's way of writing videos.

There is no easy solution to that issue, that is caused by Tesla software incorrectly setting metadata in `.mov` video files. I opened an incident with Apple and they were able to confirm this.

So I wrote some code to actually go and fix the video file by rewriting the bytes where it indicates the video track size.

Here we go, it's ugly but for the sake of completeness I wanted to post *a* solution here, if not the best.

```swift
import Foundation

struct VideoFixer {
    var url: URL
    
    private var fh: FileHandle?
    
    static func fix(_ url: URL) {
        var fixer = VideoFixer(url)
        fixer.fix()
    }
    
    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }
    
    mutating func fix() {
        guard let fh = try? FileHandle(forUpdating: url) else {
            return
        }
        
        var atom = Atom(fh)
        atom.seekTo(AtomType.moov)
        atom.enter()
        if atom.atom_type != AtomType.trak {
            atom.seekTo(AtomType.trak)
        }
        atom.enter()
        if atom.atom_type != AtomType.tkhd {
            atom.seekTo(AtomType.tkhd)
        }
        atom.seekTo(AtomType.tkhd)
        
        let data = atom.data()
        
        let width = data?.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(fromByteOffset: 76, as: UInt16.self).bigEndian }
        let height = data?.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(fromByteOffset: 80, as: UInt16.self).bigEndian }
        
        if width==4 && height==3 {
            guard let offset = try? fh.offset() else {
                return
            }
            try? fh.seek(toOffset: offset+76)
            //1280x960
            var newWidth = UInt16(1280).byteSwapped
            var newHeight = UInt16(960).byteSwapped
            let dataWidth = Data(bytes: &newWidth, count: 2)
            let dataHeight = Data(bytes: &newHeight, count: 2)
            fh.write(dataWidth)
            try? fh.seek(toOffset: offset+80)
            fh.write(dataHeight)
        }
        try? fh.close()

        
    }
}

typealias AtomType = UInt32

extension UInt32 {
    static var ftyp = UInt32(1718909296)
    static var mdat = UInt32(1835295092)
    static var free = UInt32(1718773093)
    static var moov = UInt32(1836019574)
    static var trak = UInt32(1953653099)
    static var tkhd = UInt32(1953196132)
}

struct Atom {
    var fh: FileHandle
    
    var atom_size: UInt32 = 0
    var atom_type: UInt32 = 0
    
    init(_ fh: FileHandle) {
        self.fh = fh
        
        self.read()
    }
    mutating func seekTo(_ type:AtomType) {
        while self.atom_type != type {
            self.next()
        }
    }
    mutating func next() {
        guard var offset = try? fh.offset() else {
            return
        }
        
        offset = offset-8+UInt64(atom_size)
        
        if (try? self.fh.seek(toOffset: UInt64(offset))) == nil {
            return
        }
        self.read()
    }
    mutating func read() {
        self.atom_size = fh.nextUInt32().bigEndian
        self.atom_type = fh.nextUInt32().bigEndian
    }
    mutating func enter() {
        self.atom_size = fh.nextUInt32().bigEndian
        self.atom_type = fh.nextUInt32().bigEndian
    }
    func data() -> Data? {
        guard let offset = try? fh.offset() else {
            return nil
        }
        let data = fh.readData(ofLength: Int(self.atom_size))
        try? fh.seek(toOffset: offset)
        return data
    }
}
extension FileHandle {
    func nextUInt32() -> UInt32 {
        let data = self.readData(ofLength: 4)
        let i32array = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt32.self) }
        //print(i32array)
        return i32array
    }
}
```